# React-navigation's TabNavigator - detect when tab is going out of the screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm working on a React Native app with 3 tabs. Since I'm presenting a camera feed in one of them I need to know when it's going out of the screen just to stop it. Since `componentWillUnmount` and `componentDidUnmount` are not called in this situation, I tried to use the `tabBarOnPress`. However if I'm in e.g. Tab1 screen, I can detect only clicks on the first Tab screen. So I'm able to detect when the screen receives focus, but I can't detect when it loses it. How can I achieve this?

This is what I already tried to do:

```
export const MyApp = TabNavigator({
  First: {
    screen: FirstTab
  },
  Second: {
    screen: SecondTab
  },
  Third: {
    screen: ThirdTab
  }},
  {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    swipeEnabled: false,
    backBehavior: 'none',
    animationEnabled: true,
    lazy: true,
    tabBarOptions: {
      activeTintColor: 'blue',
      inactiveTintColor: 'black',
      style: {
        backgroundColor: 'white'
      },
      indicatorStyle: {
        backgroundColor: 'white'
      }
    },
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
            tabBarOnPress: (scene, jumpToIndex) => {
                if (typeof navigation.state.params.updateState!=="undefined"){
                      navigation.state.params.updateState();
                    }
            },
        }),
  }
);


export default class First extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      updateState: this.updateState
    })
  }

  updateState=()=>{
    Alert.alert('state updated')
  }

}
```

Unfortunately this still calls `updateState()` only when touching the first tab. When touching other tabs I get this error:
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `componentWillBlur()` lifecycle method.

Few life cycle methods that may help you

```
componentWillFocus - After componentDidMount and Before the screen starts animating
componentDidFocus - After screen is animated
componentWillBlur - Before screen animates out
componentDidBlur - After screen animates out
```

or

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', this._onFocus);
    this.props.navigation.addListener('blur', this._onBlur);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.props.navigation.removeListener('blur', this._onBlur);
    this.props.navigation.removeListener('focus', this._onFocus);
  }


  _onFocus = () => {
    // Update focus state. Latter state update is to refresh the content once
    // focus state is updated. Temp fix for react navigation tab swiping issues.
    // See https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1257
    this.setState({isFocused: true}, () => { this.setState(this.state)});
  };

  _onBlur = () => {
    this.setState({isFocused: false});
  };
```

[Refer here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1257)

Comment: @fragon react-navigation-is-focused-hoc might help you

Comment: The second solution you proposed works for me, but there is a bug in react-navigation implementation, because both callbacks are called only from the second time the tab is changed.